What typeface was used on the DEC PDP-8/F faceplate?
I'm currently working on a project to create a faceplate in the style of a Digital PDP-8/F. I'd like it to look the part and would love to find what typeface and font was used on the original.
The first text in the top left is the DEC corporate logo. While someone on Wikipedia say that is Kalimati, that's not overly important as I have found an SVG of this graphic on the DEC wiki page.
The rest of the top text is lowercase making it difficult to know if the uppercase text on the controls is the same. This lower case text appears to be the same as the actual pdp8/f logo text with some modifications. However, I don't mind recreating that myself.

My search online didn't bring up any specifics. And an online font matcher came close but no cigar. That lowercase 't' is so easy to spot!

Do you know whether an existing font was used, or whether the text might have been specially designed for the machine?  (I too have found a number of very close fonts, but no exact match.)

@gidds: I expect most such things would have been done using transfer lettering, with the shapes of the letters being produced by the type founary, but the placement being done by eye (with the aid of a horizontal rule and/or blue guidelines).

Ran it through What the Font and the fonts that match the t don't match the rest.

You might try the font-identification tag at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ as well

You're welcome for the edit.  Autocorrect likely explains the typos, as the C and the P keys are quite far away on most keyboard layouts!  BTW, to which wiki page are you referring?  For some reason I'm not seeing that specific image on the DEC English Wikipedia page, but maybe you are referring to a different site or language,

Interestign that the typeface in the "digital" logo differs from the rest. There are some traces on the net (https://vt100.net/dec/logo) to who made the "digital" font, but impossible to say it was the same person. But they might still have been in house produced.

Partial answer, mainly about the logo, but possibly this gives more hints for searches:
The history of the digital variant (which probably produced the SVG file you found) is described by Ned Batchelder here:

The logo was designed in 1957 by Elliot Hendrickson, who was then working as an independent designer. He was contracted by DEC to do a brochure, and DEC wanted a logo to accompany it. The logo up to then had been the letters DEC in blocks the shape of the plug-in cards that DEC had been producing. Elliot re-worked the logo, incorporating letters which were hand-drawn for the purpose by Arthur Hover(?). The logo has been maintained since then in conventional technology, i.e. film masters. There was at least one reworking of the logo at some point.
The masters I received had a number of interesting features. The boxes were not all the same width, and there seemed to be no logic to which boxes were wider. The ‘g’ was the narrowest, and the ‘i’ and ‘l’ were second widest. Also, the two ‘i’s were not exactly the same shape. On ten-inch masters, (one box to an 8”×11” sheet), the boxes were not rectangles, but were very slightly tapered in weird ways. I assume that the tapering is the result of too many reproductions, but the difference in widths may have been deliberate at some time. Elliot reports that when he drew it, all boxes were the same width. I have made all of the boxes the same width, since that seems to have been the original intent, since the differences were almost negligible anyway, and since there was no logic to the differences.

The rest of the text describes how he resurrected a Type 3 font he made for the logo while working for DEC, by extracting it from a digital copy of a research paper.
The way the logo was designed suggest that possibly the font was also custom designed.
A mailinglist thread from 2010 suggests that this font was also used for the manuals, at least for some period, so possibly you want to have a look at the DEC manuals at bitsavers and go through the manuals they have, if you are looking for more samples of characters in the font.
I have actually seen the old DEC logo with the plugin-cards in some place or other, but I cannot remember where.

Edit: In the comments of Ned Batchelders article there is a link to this github repository, which apparently contains a remake of the font used in the Handbooks.

But it is not the original. Nevertheless, the t's look like on the faceplate...
And in case anybody is interested in the color schemas, see this discussion, which links to the DEC Standard /EL-00092 on bitsavers.

Look's like Ned's artwork is the same SVG as on https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Digital_Equipment_Corporation_1987_logo.svg That's a good one to use for the logo. Now, on to the rest of the text.

This style looks like characters drawn with lettering guides for technical drawings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lettering_guide).
